CSS Sliding Expand Menu
I have an idea for a simple expandable panel:

By default the panel is hidden
Clicking a button reveals the panel
As the panel is revealed, it expands upwards from the bottom of its parent at a consistent pace to give the illusion that it was sandwiched between its parent and the element below its parent, and it slides up into view
The panel's height is determined by its content.

I've been playing around with this concept and I've almost got it to behave exactly how I want:


    
#page {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

#main {
  border: 3px solid green;
  flex: 1 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mainContent {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#footer{
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

#slideup {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 2em);
  padding: 1em;
  bottom: 0;
  clip-path: inset(-100% 0% 0% 0%); 
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: clip-path 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  background-color: gray;
}
#slideup.hide {
  clip-path: inset(-100% 0% 100% 0%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

#folderTab {
  top: 0;
  right: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: .5rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
<div id="page">
  <div>
  Header
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="mainContent">
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
    </div>
    <div id="slideup" class="hide" >
    <div id="folderTab">
      
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">
        Click Me
      </a>
    </div>
      More stuff in here<br/>
      Only a few lines though<br/>
      And we don't really know<br/>
      just<br/>
      how<br/>
      many<br/>
      <input/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  Footer
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("slideup");
  if (x.classList.contains("hide")) {
    x.classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    x.classList.add("hide");
  }
}
</script>



https://jsfiddle.net/jd9L6wyk/28/
Problem with the example above: When the "sliding panel" all the way down and "hidden," using the tab key to focus the input at the bottom of the panel will scroll the "main" div.
How can my code be modified to achieve the desired effect without the weird tab scrolling behavior?

" Pressing tab key shows whitespace " is this your issue? . If yes then its not happening on your fiddle.

Whoops, I linked an old version of the fiddle. Updated.

Your issue can be resolved with few simple steps but first understand cause of problem.
This issue arise because your slide content is not visible in view point but its html is actually present, so when we press 'tab' it focuses on input field. Solution is to add display: none to slide content.
You need to follow this steps:

Separate your slide content with new div. In below example I have added class slideContent to that div.
As by default we want slideContent to be hidden so we will add this .slideContent{display: none;} to css.
Last part need to handle click, import slideContent in js and add y.style.display = "block"; when x contains hide and add y.style.display = "none"; in else.

That's all. Check below code example for better understanding also loved your idea slide up with button.


#page {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

#main {
  border: 3px solid green;
  flex: 1 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mainContent {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#footer{
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

#slideup {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 2em);
  padding: 1em;
  bottom: 0;
  clip-path: inset(-100% 0% 0% 0%); 
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: clip-path 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  background-color: gray;
}
#slideup.hide {
  clip-path: inset(-100% 0% 100% 0%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

#folderTab {
  top: 0;
  right: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: .5rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.slideContent{display: none;}
<div id="page">
  <div>
  Header
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="mainContent">
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
      Main Content<br/>
      This is a bunch of <br/>
      important text<br/>
      We have no idea how many lines it will be<br/>
    </div>
    <div id="slideup" class="hide" >
    <div id="folderTab">
      
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">
        Click Me
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slideContent">
      More stuff in here<br/>
      Only a few lines though<br/>
      And we don't really know<br/>
      just<br/>
      how<br/>
      many<br/>
      <input/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  Footer
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("slideup");
  var y = document.querySelector(".slideContent");
  if (x.classList.contains("hide")) {
    x.classList.remove("hide");
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.classList.add("hide");
    setTimeout(()=>{
    y.style.display = "none";    
    },1000)
  }
}
</script>




This totally fixes the problem! But, it also does something kind of funny: the instant that you've clicked the button to hide the sliding pane, the content disappears and the animation jumps to accommodate that. I wonder if there's a way to set display: none without using more javascript or the poorly supported transition-behavior: allow-discrete

@BoThompson, We can fix the jumping issue with ease by adding setTimeout in js. Yes you can add display: none without js by adding checkbox so if  its checked then display would be block or else it will be none but this approach is less flexible and you need to do lot of unnecessary work. If you still consider js I have edited code to fix jumping issue.
